# How common is the style of Style Cops default configuration?

Tags: c#, coding-style, stylecop

I have used Style Cop for making sure people follow set code standards before but then configured it to our needs. For a few days now I have used Style Cop with its default setting to try it out and I'm a bit puzzled by some things. For instance, if I declare a variable I really like to state what type it is.

```
 int foo;
```

or

```
 Bar foo = new Bar();
```

Style Cop wants you to use the `var` keyword a lot.
I understand that you, the compiler and the IDE can figure out the type by the instantiation.

```
  var foo = 1; // Makes foo and int
  var foo = new Bar(); // Makes foo a Bar
```

When declaration and instantiation is done in one step it's fairly visible whats going on.

There are a few more things that I'm not quite comfortable with that Style Cop seems to like so I basically just wanna know how common is the coding style enforced by the standard Style Cop configuration, and where does it originate from?

**Note: This usage below of `var` is not valid as stated by hvd. Made me feel a bit better of `var` straight away ;). I leave it in since it was in the original question though**

But if you have some obscure thing like

```
  var foo

     ... bunch of code ...

     foo = getLatestData();
```

It's not obvious what `foo` becomes. But looking at the declaration of `foo` you won't get any smarter. Instead you have to look at the declaration of the `getLatestData` function.

I feel that the `var` approach clouds everything a bit. There is no strict control like you get if you declare that `foo` is a `int`. Then you know that `foo` is *always* an `int`. It doesn't depend what it get's its data from. Something like this could very well give you two different types of foo.

```
var foo;

...

if(status == 0) {
  foo = getLatestData();
}
else {
  foo = getOtherData();
}
```

There's nothing enforcing that the two functions have to return the same type and `foo` can thus become different things. When you code everything yourself and it's contained like this it's probably easy to keep track of. But if it's an API or plugin library it would be a nightmare if external 3rd party developers cold dictate the type of `foo` since you could not be sure what to do with it in that case.

Comment: `var foo;` isn't valid. `var` can only be used with an initialiser, and only the type of the initialiser is used.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes me feel better about it already ;)

Comment: You can always customize Stylecop rule set and actually you must do that (for example many Stylecop rules conflict with Resharper rules), just make sure, that this rule set is used by all developers in the team. And the "Then you know that foo is ALWAYS and int. It doesn't depend what it get's it's data from" - in my opinion it is a  good thing - if I make change to my method to return long instead of int, I won't need to modify code consuming that method.

Comment: In the `var foo = 1` case you know that `foo` is always an `int`. `var` is not `dynamic` - the type is taken from the initialiser and is thereafter static. It's really just a convenience. Personally I use it a lot, particularly for object types - I think `var list = new List<BigLongTypeName>()` is preferable to `List<BigLongTypeName> list = new List<BigLongTypeName>()` which is a bit repetitive and redundant.

Comment: I'm convinced about var ;)... But where does the rest of it all come from? Is there a large convention where people debate or did someone just decide that this should be the default rules? :)

Comment: I think the introduction on the style cop site sums it up http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=A%20Brief%20History%20of%20CSharp%20Style&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: I don't think there is a real question left to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question has some misconceptions about [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) which have been picked up in the comments and clarified in the linked MSDN reference.

As to the actual question, I would infer that the code style enforced by the default Style Cop rule set is at least as common as the usage of the default Style Cop rule set. This answer is a tautology of course but, correct for the remnant of the question.

If you have more concerns about the `var` keyword you could  consult many of the existing answers on the subject, here on Stack Overflow.